# How do I create a snippet that inserts \{\} using escape characters?

Tags: sublimetext3, key-bindings, code-snippets

I am trying to create a snippet in sublime text that when I press ctrl+shift+[ it inserts the snippet `\{\}`, but I am having trouble working out how to use escape characters to do it.

Here is what I have:

```
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+shift+["], 
    "command": "insert_snippet", 
    "args": {
        "contents": "\\{\\}"
    }
}
```

but when I use the keyboard shortcut, it only inserts `{}` without the backslashes! It is strange because when I change it to just `"\\"` then the output is `\`, but when something comes after the two backslashes, it ignores the backslash.

I have found a work around of sorts using the ChainOfCommand package that inserts each character separately like this:

```
{ 
    "keys": ["ctrl+shift+["], 
    "command": "chain", 
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            ["insert_snippet", {"contents": "\\"}],
            ["insert_snippet", {"contents": "{"}],
            ["insert_snippet", {"contents": "\\"}],
            ["insert_snippet", {"contents": "}"}]
        ]
    }
}
```

but the problem with that is that if I then do a ctrl-z undo, it will remove each character one at a time, instead of removing the whole snippet, which is annoying. Also, its just the principle of the thing, I should be able to do it in one snippet I am sure!

Does anyone have any idea how I can make it work?

Comment: If you don't want to insert a snippet (i.e. don't use $1, $2, ...) you can also use `insert` with "normal" json escapes: `{"keys": ["ctrl+shift+["], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "\\{\\}"} },`

Comment: Ah cool, thats good to know! thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As un-intuitive as it may seem, using the following keybinding will insert `\{\}`:

```
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+shift+["], 
    "command": "insert_snippet", 
    "args": {
        "contents": "\\\\{\\\\}"
    }
},
```

The reason for this is explained at: https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1878#issuecomment-328133400:

> Due to compatibility with TextMate snippets, the following characters must be escaped to be literal:
>
> `\`, `$`, `{`, `}`
>
> Any other `\{CHAR}` will be produced verbatim. This explains why a single backslash is fine, but two become a single.

In case it helps, you can also execute the following in the ST console to see the difference that the JSON extra-escaping makes (compared to, for example, the same content inside a `.sublime-snippet` file):

```
view.run_command('insert_snippet', { 'contents': r'\\{\\}' })
```

Comment: ah okay, that makes sense, so you need to escape the escape character and then escape the `{` character as well! i was trying to see if i could escape the escape character with `"\\\{\\\}"`, but it didn't work, i should have gone one more! Thanks so much for your help!